# Linux file command classifying files

Tags: linux, file

I need to recognize type of data contained in random files. I am new to Linux and need help.

I am planning to use "file" command to understand what type of data a file has. I tried that command and got below screenshot. 
I have a few questions as below:

Does 'file' command actually goes through the content of a file to determine the data type or does it just look at the extension of a file?

What are different possible answers that I could get after running the 'file' command. For example in below screenshot I am getting JPEG, ISO media, ASCII etc

I looked at the [page](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_file.htm) but felt that it was too technical..Would appreciate if anyone can provide a link which has much simpler explanation..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks at the first few bytes of a file to work out what sort of file it is. It will try not to scan the whole file, and it won't take the extension into account at all.

You'll need to try it out to see what different possible answers you can get, but there are thousands...

The most useful general rule about its output is that any output with the word "text" in refers to something that you can read with a text viewer, and anything without "text" is some kind of binary.

Bear in mind that file isn't perfect: sometimes it won't know the exact file type, and it'll make a guess, but won't always get it exactly right.

Comment: My main goal is to classify a file into one of the 5 categories - image, video, sound, text- generic, text - numeric or other. I understand "text" refers to text - generic or text-numeric. How can I classify a file into image, video, sound or other class? can I use binary representation of file produced by 'xxd -b' command?

Comment: I don't think there's any perfect answer to that. You should certainly still use file; you might find that it always puts 'image' in the output when it's an image, etc., but if not, you can at least check the output of file against a list of known outputs for known image types.

Comment: The reason you can't get a perfect answer is: suppose I create a new image file format that you don't know about. How can you possibly classify the file as being an image? What you really care about is identifying them as being images of particular types that you know about, and that means checking the output against known cases. I'd start by writing a script that does what you say but uses 'other' when in doubt, and then add in more cases of known file types as you go.

Comment: Your answers and suggestions make sense. Can I use binary representation of files that I get by using command 'xxd -b' to perform the classification? Would binary representation have anything more useful that "file" command doesnt look at?

Comment: No, you're reinventing the wheel if you do that. That's essentially what file is doing.

Comment: To test your earlier comment - "you might find that it always puts 'image' in the output when it's an image, etc., " I want to run the command on variety of image files. I found that there are 23 image formats - http://www.altools.com/ALTools/ALSee/Features/View-23-Image-Formats.aspx What is the easiest way to download an image of each format? I would like to avoid downloading a file at a time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59543/discussion-between-user2543622-and-chiastic-security).

Comment: any inputs? would like to hear them...